# Upstart is not seeing my new script

Tags: upstart

I've added a new script to `/etc/init/` called `minecraft.conf` which contains the script:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

script
  export HOME="/root"
  exec /root/minecraft/start.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/minecraft.log
end script

post-start script
   echo "minecraft started"
```

When I try `start minecraft` I get the error: `start: Unknown job: minecraft`

I've tried running `initctl list` and my minecraft job is not listed. I've tried running `initctl reload-configuration` and it doesn't make any difference.

Other jobs listed by `initctl list` work fine with start, stop and restart.

Why won't upstart see my new script?

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Comment: This might be a stupid question but... shuldn't be your script in `/etc/init.d/`?

Comment: @snow thanks, but I've already read that and I still have the problem.

Comment: @Wolfer according to the upstart getting started guide, it says "Once happy, place the files in `/etc/init` and now you're ready to reboot and use upstart."

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but with no success. I copy pasted your code to /etc/init/minecraft.conf and issued `sudo start minecraft` without a problem. 

Here is content of the log file `~$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/minecraft.log 
minecraft started
/proc/self/fd/9: 3: exec: /root/minecraft/start.sh: not found
minecraft started`
Can you provide more details on Ubuntu version you are using and any useful information from syslog?

Comment: @schkovich Running Ubuntu 12.10 x64 Server, and I can't see anything related to upstart, or otherwise useful in syslog...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I feel kinda dumb... But here it is:

I missed the "end script" stanza from the very end of the upstart script...

```
post-start script
   echo "minecraft started"
```

should have been

```
post-start script
   echo "minecraft started"
end script
```

I'm not sure why it worked for @schkovich without the `end script`, though...

Comment: Because I added end script stanza. Built in (mind) auto code completion. :(

Comment: I hit the same problem but infuriatingly, nothing appears in /var/log and initctl reload-configuration --verbose is silent.

Answer (score 13):

An easy way to check your script syntax is with the following command:

```
init-checkconf -d /etc/init/service_name.conf
```

I've found that even with a valid Upstart file if the file didn't exist when the server was booted last I have to reboot the server for Upstart to see the file.

Answer (score 12):

Check the upstart logs (it's in `/var/log/syslog`) while reloading the configuration using `initctl reload-configuration`. If there is a syntax error, it will show up there. That's usually why you cannot use your new upstart configuration.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was an empty `author` field, like this:

```
author ""
```

It worked only after adding something in the quotes.

```
# initctl reload-configuration
```

was also throwing `/etc/init/servicename.conf:2: Expected token` **to syslog instead of stdout**. Too busy to file a bug report for a dying package.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not applicable to this specifically, but worth mentioning: If you edit a Upstart config file for a service that is running, running `restart` does NOT reload the configuration. You have to run `stop` and `start` to have new changes take effect.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#restart

Answer (score 1):

Alternative command for new Ubuntu versions (works on 18):

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```