# Upstart not detecting the new job on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upstart

I am unable to get Upstart to recognize my new job. I've checked the upstart cookbook, as well as various questions on the matter, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247077/upstart-is-not-seeing-my-new-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). All the checks pass, but `initctl list` does not show my job. I've rebooted multiple times for good measure, too.

Here's the job description that I placed in `/etc/init/jenkins-agent.conf`:

```
author "Jenkins-admin"
description "Jenkins agent"

start on local-filesystems and started networking
respawn

exec java -jar /home/jenkins/jenkins/Agent/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://127.0.0.1:8087/jenkins/computer/Ubuntu%2064-bit/slave-agent.jnlp -secret d1ac22621ad4c460e5f8de4f393ed2702cdb2bea1d26b6f17230451a37a08e7e -workDir "/home/jenkins/jenkins"
```

- `init-checkconf /etc/init/jenkins-agent.conf` says: `syntax ok`
- `initctl check-config` only displays two warnings for one other .conf file. No warnings about my file.
- `initctl list | grep jenkins` output is blank.
- `sudo inictl` commands, like `sudo inictl list` result in "initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused"

What else can I try? Tempted to forget upstart and just write an `init.d` script which has always worked flawlessly for me, but I would like to figure it out since upstart is the new default way of running startup jobs.

Comment: wrong init system: use systemd instead. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: @muru: Odd. I've googled for `init` vs `init.d` and was led to believe `init` is the new way and `init.d` is the old way. What a spectacular way to waste two hours, huh. Thanks.

Comment: `init.d` was the old way and `init` the new way from ~10.04 - 14.10. `init.d` and `init` are the old ways and systemd the new way from 15.04 - (present).

Comment: @muru: thanks, now I see where I made the wrong turn. That explains.